# how do you use ごと

Tags: grammar, word-choice

hi i found ごと through immersion and when i looked it up it says it is a normalizing suffix can anyone clear this out for me i am still confused of how to use this word.

example sentence if it helps

えらい他人事だな

Comment: Are you sure this isn't こと as a nominalizer? If not, can you provide more context? Where did you see this and can you provide examples?

Comment: 他人事 is a [set phrase](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E4%BB%96%E4%BA%BA%E4%BA%8B) meaning "someone else's business", so it's not a good example to use for your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

事【こと】 is used to **nominalize** (not normalize) verbs, in other words turn a verb like "to eat" 食べる into "eating" 食べること as in 食べることが好き "I like eating".

事 can basically be translated as "thing / matter" and in the case of 他人事 it means "the things concerning other people" / "other peoples affairs". Note that it can also occur in words such as "human resources" 人事【じんじ】.